# traefik returns wrong content type for jpeg images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gzip, traefik

I'm using several containers in my website to do different tasks and the traefik(v2.2) container is used as router to these containers.
the problem is, treafik compresses all server responses using gzip algorithm. even if I disable compression using "compress = false" in docker-compose file, at the same time it adds wrong content-type to some of my jpeg images and it makes "some" images unreadable for browsers.
treafik will add auto-detected content-type to those responses which doesn't have content-type already.

I searched a while and according to official documentations gzip algorithm itself may cause problem for some jpeg images.([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding))

Now I just have a bunch of guesses about the origin of the problem. and unable to solve it after trying few hours.

do you have any idea?

if you need any specefic data,please ask!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue for traefik to auto detect and set a default value to Content-Type if none is provided in response.

And this pr fix it by disabling the auto detection.

https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/6097